# Specifying the Python interpreter for vim's :python command

Tags: python, vim, environment-variables

(Mac)Vim seems to be picking up `/usr/bin/python` instead of the one that's at the front of my path (`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/python`) when I use the :python command. Is this entirely a compile-time thing or can I somehow override it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Seems like it is an entirely compile-time thing:

```
$ ldd /usr/bin/vim | grep python
libpython2.5.so.1.0 => /usr/lib/libpython2.5.so.1.0 (0xb6bcc000)
```

my `vim --version` also reports being built against a specific python.

```
$ vim --version | tr '-' '\n' | grep python
+python +quickfix +reltime +rightleft +ruby +scrollbind +signs +smartindent 
I/usr/include/python2.5 
L/usr/lib/python2.5/config 
lpython2.5
```

another symptom of this is that the `:python` command won't work with vim unless `vim --version` reports +python.

Comment: +1, correct, vim **is** indeed designed to use (embed) the Python library it's compiled and linked with (if any) -- which is also the normal way for any C or C++ application to embed Python, of course.

Comment: Thanks Paul, Alex. I've gone and recompiled MacVim, it turned out to be not as painful as I'd expected.

Comment: Note that Paul wrote what's probably the easiest way around this right now! I use ipython (installed for the system python) to send commands to an ipython kernel on the python I want to "use." python-mode or similar could support such behavior too (though it's heavy use of :python would require you to rewrite the run#Run function). This is really only a limitation for running things with :python, which you only _need_ to do to script vim itself.

Comment: Looks like it's not the case now. I don't know the details. I just tried `:python import sys; print sys.executable;` and it is indeed affected by `$PATH`.

Comment: It is possible to use Python libraries from other locations by adding `export PYTHONPATH="/home/user-name/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages":$PYTHONPATH` to `~/.zshrc`/. However, this does not change the interpreter.